# Post processing a template in freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker, post-processing

I am trying to generate an email using freemarker template library. Email is intended to be sent to multiple user. Furthermore except the user name all details are same.

So I don't want to process template with same data for different user. Is there any way to post process a template in freemarker. Any other workaround would be helpful as well.

Thanks

Comment: You want to post-process exactly what? Because it sounds like you want to post-process the *output*, which is really just a `String`, so you could just have a `<userName>` there that you search-and-replace. Though I would think that running `Template.process` in a loop is fast enough, as far as the data-model is fast (like it doesn't run DB queries).

Comment: For now i used the same workaround you mentioned, I replaced the <userName> using search-replace after template has been processed, and it worked for me. Thanks anyways.